Robocopy Filemove is consuming 100% cpu
I am running my Powershell script on server VM, with 32 GB Ram with 8 cores on a Xeon gold processor. OS Win2k 2016.
The script uses runspace pool to create 10 sessions and threads. Basically i am trying to move files based on the criteria below in robocopy, in a fairly large datastore of about 35 TB. The datastore and the server where this being run are at different data centers and have a good WAN connection.
Here is the code below
I am not sure what is causing my script to run at 100% CPU. Any help is greatly appreciated.
    $Copy_Folders = {
Param  (
        [string]$folderName,
        [string]$dest        
       )

robocopy $folderName $dest /S /mt:8 /MINAGE:20180101 /nfl /np /ndl /NJH /NJS /MOVE /XD "1011" "_-_Audio_-_" "_-_Video_-_" "Global Files" "Archived" /XF "mp4*.*" "mp3*.*" ' 
     
    $filename = "Archived"
    $folderPath = Join-Path -Path $folderName -ChildPath $filename
 
    # Check Folder Exists, if it doesn't then create it
    If(! (Test-Path -Path $folderPath )){
           
        #Create a New Folder with Date Timestamp   
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $folderPath         
    }                          
}


# Multithreading the file transfer process 
$numThreads  = 10
$maxSessions = 10

$folders = @()

#Start the time 
$stopwatch.Start()

#TEST ONLY
$src = "X:\Audio Files\Old-Audio\"
$dest = "Y:\Audio Files\Old-Audio"

$Runspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $numThreads)
$Runspace.ApartmentState = 'STA'
$Runspace.Open()

$Jobs = @()

$folders = ls $src
$folders = $folders | Sort-Object -Property{$_.Name -as [int]}

Write-Output "Total number of folders to process:" $folders.Count
Write-Output "Copying folders to archive"


$folders | % {

    $folderName = $_.FullName    
    Write-Output $folderName
    $Job = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Copy_Folders).AddParameter("folder", $folderName).AddParameter("dest", $dest)
    $Job.RunspacePool = $Runspace
   
    $Jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      RunNum = $_
      Job = $Job
      Result = $Job.BeginInvoke()      
   }

   #Write-Host ("Thread Count: {0} Elapsed Time: {1}"-f $Jobs.Count, $stopwatch.Elapsed) -ForegroundColor Yellow   
}

$Counter = 1

Do{
   #Write-Host " " $Counter " " -NoNewline
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   $Counter++
}While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false)  #Jobs.Result is a collection

Write-Output " "


# EndInvoke returns the objects from the background threads
$return = $jobs | % {    
    $_.Job.RunspacePool.Dispose()       
    $_.job.Dispose()    
}

Write-Host "Number of Folders added from Job: " $jobs.Count
$jobs.clear()
$Runspace.Close()
[GC]::Collect() 

Write-Output "All files moved in: " $stopwatch.Elapsed


If you look in Task Manager, what is using the most cpu? Powershell or robocopy?  Does it change if you reduce your parallelism to, say, 2, or even 1? What if you increase your sleep to, say 30 seconds as a test?

You use .AddParameter("folder", ..., but the script itself takes a parameter called folderName. It is also best to avoid the += construct because that is extremely time and memory consuming

Thank you. The Robocopy is the one taking most of the cpu.

I was able to make it work, by reducing the number of threads and sessions to just 5.
